# Groovy mistakenly using constructor of enclosing class?

Tags: groovy, constructor, inner-classes

Given:

```
static class Question {
    // stuff
    List<Value> values

    static class Value {
        // stuff
    }
```

When I run:

```
Question question = new Question()
question.id = "whatever"

if (it == QuestionType.SELECT || it == QuestionType.MULTICHOICE) {
    question.values = [new Question.Value(), new Question.Value()]

    for (Question.Value v : question.values) {
        // stuff
    }
```

`question.values` contains an array of Question objects and NOT Value.

Intellij doesn't give me any error nor warnings. I tried evaluating "new Question.Value()" during debug and it correctly constructed a Value object.

However, if I use a static import:

```
import static <path>.Question.*
```

And thus transforming the `if` content to:

```
question.values = [new Value(), new Value()]

for (Value v : question.values) {
    // stuff
}
```

Then I correctly get an array of Value objects!

It doesn't make any sense to me... can anybody enlighten me, please?

Edit: [image: Intellij pics] [image: Intellij pics]

Comment: Are you sure it is not IJ showing it wrongly? If I execute `class Question { List<Value> values; static class Value { } }; Question question = new Question(); question.values = [new Question.Value(), new Question.Value()]; for (Question.Value v : question.values) { println v; }
` in a Groovy Console, I get `Question$Value@411a1e3d\nQuestion$Value@61e63d22` as result as expected.

Comment: @Vampire it's not a debugger thing. I was able to reproduce it easily. Had to duplicate the question but it should be far easier to pick it up from here, take a look yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47558846/groovy-constructs-an-instance-of-an-inner-static-class-with-a-wrong-type-bug

Comment: Ok, but i don't unterstand why you created a duplicate instead of just updating your question. You should at least delete the old one then.