# Groovy constructs an instance of an inner static class with a wrong type (bug?)

Tags: groovy

The former question was posted here: [Groovy mistakenly using constructor of enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556253/groovy-mistakenly-using-constructor-of-enclosing-class)

I've scrapped all the noise by preparing a self-contained executable script which reproduces the issue.

To allow script execution of the `assert` statement, the example must be saved with a different file name than the top level class name (if the example is split into two separate files the same happens anyway):

```
package whatever

import static whatever.Foo.Bar

class Foo {
    static class Bar {
        static class Baz {
        }
    }
}

assert new Bar.Baz() instanceof whatever.Foo.Bar.Baz
```

The assert shouldn't fail but it does with:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert new Bar.Baz() instanceof whatever.Foo.Bar.Baz
       |             |
       |             false
       whatever.Foo$Bar@5ffead27

    at whatever.Weird.run(Weird.groovy:15)
```

Why, even though, the `Baz` class is explicitly being constructed, in runtime it appears to be an instance of its parent class `Bar`?

This happens only with static imports and seems like a bug...

Groovy version: 2.4.12

Comment: Note that there are a handful of open bugs in the Groovy JIRA around nested inner classes. I couldn't find an exact match but might look at this (or  those related to it) - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8359

Comment: I've noticed before asking here, thanks. Just wanted to see what Stack folks would say before I raise another bug over there.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result in the latest groovy version.

Comment: @aristotll the latest stable 2.4.13 or which one? I've tried all up to 2.6 alpha and the issue was there. The only one I haven't tried is 3.0 alpha.